# How to detect neck,wrist and ear using opencv?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I am new to use opencv to detect different parts of body just like Ear,Neck,Wrist,Face,etc....

Faces and ear can be detected from the camera But I need to detect the remaining parts of body..

How to detect them ?

I tried the all given haarcascade_XXX.xml files but I can't found any haarcascade_neck.xml or haarcascade_wrist.xml files though I can detect them.

I don't know what to do please help me....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi it's not that easy you'll have  to develope your own algorithm to do this, I don't know if you have any exprience in DIP but it's pretty complicated(the stuff you want to do ). And to get more or better help  you'll need to put what you've tried !

Comment: you could train your own cascades, but i would not bet any money on it. wrists and neck just don't have enough detail for that kind of thing. you probably need to find the face first, then guess, what might be below that, or the hand, and then see, what it's appended to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already tried this one, Here the OpenCV is able to detect eyes and tries to put the object at the points of the detected location.

But this it's not enough I also want to detect the neck and wrist...

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

class My_Panel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private BufferedImage image;
private CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
private Point center;
private JLabel label;

public My_Panel() {
    super();


    Image scalledItemImage = null;
    try {
        scalledItemImage = ImageIO.read(new File("5.png"));
        scalledItemImage= scalledItemImage.getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_FAST);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(scalledItemImage ));
    add(label);
    face_cascade = new CascadeClassifier(
            "haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml");
    if (face_cascade.empty()) {
        System.out.println("--(!)Error loading A\n");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Face classifier loooaaaaaded up");
    }
}

private BufferedImage getimage() {

    return image;
}

public void setimage(BufferedImage newimage) {
    image = newimage;
    return;
}

public BufferedImage matToBufferedImage(Mat matrix) {
    int cols = matrix.cols();
    int rows = matrix.rows();
    int elemSize = (int) matrix.elemSize();
    byte[] data = new byte[cols * rows * elemSize];
    int type;
    matrix.get(0, 0, data);
    switch (matrix.channels()) {
    case 1:
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        break;
    case 3:
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
        // bgr to rgb
        byte b;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 3) {
            b = data[i];
            data[i] = data[i + 2];
            data[i + 2] = b;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return null;
    }
    BufferedImage image2 = new BufferedImage(cols, rows, type);
    image2.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, cols, rows, data);
    return image2;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    BufferedImage temp = getimage();
    g.drawImage(temp, 10, 10, temp.getWidth(), temp.getHeight(), this);
}

public Mat detect(Mat inputframe) {
    Mat mRgba = new Mat();
    Mat mGrey = new Mat();
    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
    inputframe.copyTo(mRgba);
    inputframe.copyTo(mGrey);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGrey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.equalizeHist(mGrey, mGrey);
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(mGrey, faces);
    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces",
            faces.toArray().length));
    for (Rect rect : faces.toArray()) {
        center = new Point(rect.x + rect.width * 0.5, rect.y + rect.height
                * 0.5);
        // Core.ellipse(mRgba, center, new Size(rect.width * 0.5,
        // rect.height * 0.5), 0, 0, 360, new Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4,
        // 8, 0);
        // Core.rectangle(mRgba, center, new Point(rect.width * 0.5,
        // rect.height * 0.5), new Scalar(25, 0, 25),2);
        label.setLocation((int) center.x, (int) center.y);

        setVisible(true);
        repaint();
    }
    return mRgba;
}
}

public class MyWindow {
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    // Load the native library.
    BufferedImage temp;
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    String window_name = "Capture - Face detection";
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(window_name);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    My_Panel my_panel = new My_Panel();
    frame.setContentPane(my_panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Mat webcam_image = new Mat();
    VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);
    if (capture.isOpened()) {
        while (true) {
            capture.read(webcam_image);

            if (!webcam_image.empty()) {
                frame.setSize(webcam_image.width() + 40,
                        webcam_image.height() + 60);
                webcam_image = my_panel.detect(webcam_image);
                temp = my_panel.matToBufferedImage(webcam_image);
                my_panel.setimage(temp);
                my_panel.repaint();
            } else {
                System.out.println(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: again, don't waste your time [trying that](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html), it won't work. there's just a limit, what you can achieve with cascades. in your case, the input is inappropriate.

Comment: Hey @Gopal00005,  Have you find any solution for neck and wrist detection in android? please help...i am looking for same.

Comment: Nope, I managed it by setting an object position. Eg. I needed to detect the neck for that I was detecting the face and then I was putting an object(ornament) just lower to that detected position. The same applies to the wrist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem..tried many ways to do it but still no accurate.
Solution I have tried 
1>Get the chin point from ASM detector(With MUCT database) to detect chin point and by biometric calculation just add the half height of rectangle detected from Haarcascade of face.
2>Train your own ASM for the neck detection.You need to collect samples of the images and train it.Use Haarcasade for upper body part detection.Plenty of tutorial are available to train the ASM.

But let me remind you both are approximate solution,it may fail for most of the cases.

Comment: i cant share the exact code or the solution,but I tried training ASM. Although it is not so great but works fine if the image is proper.
Plenty of tutorials are available for the ASM training,you can refer to the Pact Tutorial Collection for asm detection.Use Head and shoulder haar xml file for training available at "http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34".

Training ASM is not easy task but you will end up leaning very interesting thing in Opencv,try it!